# Expanding an inverse distance by Legendre polynomials

Tags: legendre-polynomials, spherical-harmonics

Given two coordinates in space, I want to expand the inverse distance 
$$
I=\frac{1}{|\mathbf r_1 - \mathbf r_2|} 
$$
as a function of their respective spherical angles $(\theta_1,\phi_1)$ and $(\theta_2,\phi_2)$.

To this end, we notice that $I$ can be written as the generating function for the Legendre polynomials

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{|\mathbf r_1 - \mathbf r_2|} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2\cos(\gamma)}} \\
&= \frac{1}{r_1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2-2rx\cos(\gamma)}} \quad x:=\frac{r_2}{r_1} \\
&= \frac{1}{r_1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k P_k(\cos \gamma) \ ,
\end{align}
where $\gamma$ denotes the angle between the coordinates $\angle(\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2)$. $P_k(\cos\gamma)$ are our Legendre polynomials in $\cos(\gamma)$.

---

I now want to rewrite the last expression in terms of spherical angles, at which I'm stuck. Any hint are highly appreciated.

---

**Context**

In calculating the expectation value $\big\langle \psi_0 \big|\frac{1}{|\mathbf r_1 -\mathbf r_2|} \big| \psi_0 \big\rangle $ of the two-electron approximate ground state $\psi_0(\mathbf r_1, \mathbf r_2)$ of the He atom, all $P_k$ with $k>0$ will vanish in the integral
\begin{align}
\bigg\langle \frac{1}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|} \bigg\rangle &= \bigg( \frac{8}{\pi a^3} \bigg)^2
\int_{\mathbf{r}_1 \in \mathbb R^3} 
\int_{\mathbf{r}_2 \in \mathbb R^3}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{(\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2)^2}}
e^{-4(r_1+ r_2)/a} d\mathbf r_1 d \mathbf r_2 \ .
\end{align}

As it turned out, I was able to solve it in [a more simple manner](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/311180/45742), by using a change of variables. But I'm still interested in solving it with this method using Legendre polynomials.